# I cannot build my ios product when I using product > archive in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-ios-build

I cannot build my ios product when I using product > archive in xcode...

I used flutter to development and I had did run flutter ios build --release.

Then I go to xcode running product > archive, I get this error

```
Showing All Issues
Multiple commands produce '/Users/yomate/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ddhhkruxpbzezodlfgvmogmaieov/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':
1) Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output '/Users/yomate/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ddhhkruxpbzezodlfgvmogmaieov/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
2) Target 'GoogleUtilities-54e75ca4' has create directory command with output '/Users/yomate/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ddhhkruxpbzezodlfgvmogmaieov/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
```

Where has problem? I had did successful 2 days ago, but I need to update the version now, it was got error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried to add it in pod

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.7.0'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end


target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.7.0'
end
```